# Install Dropbox and set my www folder as the synced folder on the server

Tags: server, file-sharing, dropbox

I want to sync my WWW folder with dropbox.
How can I do that ?

I am using Ubuntu server 12.xx something. This for development purpose only.

I goggled it but I was unsuccessful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you want X folder in dropbox (~/Dropbox/X) to act as your www root folder, edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and replace `/var/www/` with `/home/<username>/Dropbox/X`. Make sure that files inside the `X` folder are readable by `www-data` user.
2. If you want to add `/var/www/` to your Dropbox, and keep it synced, create a symlink inside `~/Dropbox/` to point to `/var/www`

   ```
   cd ~/Dropbox
   ln -s /var/www www
   ```

   (You might wanna `chown` the www folder, so as to add files to it, without using root.

Comment: what owner/group/permission should i give it?